# Is this the optimal MySQL database schema for a website that can become huge?

Tags: php, mysql

Im sketching out a database layout for a website that has the potential to become huge with 100's of queries a minute.

I was thinking about doing the following:

**user table**
id
name
*(few more fields)*

**Pages** (this one will become the biggest table)
id
titel
img
text
*restaurant (this will be the row that connects the pages to the user table, i was planning on creating an index on this one to increase speed)*

So im wondering if creating an index for the 'restaurant' row will increase the speed of my queries or if there is any other way to speed up things?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Build your schema, fill it with test data, and benchmark it.  If you're really concerned about how it will perform, this is the only thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do some query like :

```
select *
from pages
where restaurant = ...
```

Or like :

```
select *
from user
    inner join pages on pages.restaurant = user.id
where user.name = '...'
```

Or any other condition on the `restaurant` column, then, you'll probably want to add an index on that column, to avoid scanning all lines on the `pages` table.

But note that useful/necessary indexes will almost always depend on the kind of queries you'll be doing.

Which means that it's not quite possible to accurately *guess* which indexes you'll need -- first, you need to know how you will access you data.

**Note :** you should read the [**How MySQL Uses Indexes**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html) section of MySQL's manual : it contains stuff that's interesting to know ;-)

Comment: It will mostly be a search query that will look a lot like the second query you posted. User searches for a certain dish, finds it at a restaurant and the page will show all dishes for that restaurant

Comment: In this case, you are using the `restaurant` as a filter, and an index *(which should be part of a foreign key)* on it will likely help.

Comment: Cheers for the advice, going to run a few tests now to see how it all goes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As a test, you can always run your query in your preferred tool and add `EXPLAIN` in front. This will show you what indices are being used and/or which temporary tables had to be created etc.

```
EXPLAIN select *
from pages
where restaurant = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the InnoDB storage, you should not just use 'an index' but make use of [`FOREIGN KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html). Thus, you will also decrease potential integrity problems.

Suggestion: do not use `restaurant` as a name. Add some more tables and it will be difficult to keep track what references what. Why not call it `user_id`? (This is a matter of personal preference, though.)

Comment: Cheers for the innoDB tip! I am using user_id, and dish_id in real life :)